# Google Analytics error

Tags: google-analytics

I have add google analytics code to google tag manager and google tag manager connected to my website using script. 
After this google analytics not showing active users in real time and in chrome browser google analytics shows red color tag with the error 'No HTTP response detected'.

Is, there know how to fix this.

Comment: This means the GA code is detected, but it does not send information to the tracking server. There is not enough information in your question to determine why this is happening. If possible give a link to your site, if not show what tracking code you are using.

Comment: @Kumar, I can solve this issue, can you share more information. I think you are missing some steps in the GTM.

Comment: Eike and user3816325 the issue was fixed, thanks for reply friends.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to install Google Tag Assistant https://get.google.com/tagassistant/

It might help you out